# Evaluation of $ \int_{0}^{1}\left(\sqrt[4]{1-x^7}-\sqrt[7]{1-x^4}\right)dx$

Tags: calculus

> Evaluation of $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}\left(\sqrt[4]{1-x^7}-\sqrt[7]{1-x^4}\right)dx$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ We can write it as $$I =  \displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}\sqrt[4]{1-x^7}dx-\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt[7]{1-x^4}dx$$

Now Using $$\displaystyle \bullet \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx = -\int_{b}^{a}f(x)dx$$

So  we get $$I =  \displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}\left(1-x^7\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}dx+\int_{1}^{0}\left(1-x^4\right)^{\frac{1}{7}}dx$$

Now Let $$\displaystyle f(x) = \left(1-x^{7}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}\;,$$ Then $$f^{-1}(x) = (1-x^4)^{\frac{1}{7}}$$ and also $f(0) = 1$ and $f(1) =0$

So Integral $$\displaystyle I = \int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx+\int_{f(0)}^{f(1)}f^{-1}(x)dx$$

Now let $f^{-1}(x) = z\;,$ Then $x=f(z)$ So we get $dx = f'(z)dz$

So Integral $$\displaystyle I =\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx+\int_{0}^{1}z\cdot f'(z)dz$$

Now Integration by parts for second Integral, We get

$$\displaystyle I  =\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx+\left[z\cdot f(z)\right]_{0}^{1}-\int_{0}^{1}f(z)dz$$

So using $$\displaystyle \bullet\; \int_{a}^{b}f(z)dz = \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$$

So we get $$\displaystyle I =\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx+f(1) -\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx = f(1) =0$$

My Question is can we solve it Some $\bf{short\;  way,}$ Iy yes then plz explain here

Thanks

Comment: Each integral finds the first-quadrant area under the curve $s^4+t^7=1$.

Comment: This has also been discussed on Mathlinks some time ago: http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1097276

Comment: Great example of a well-constructed question.  +1

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1336604/solve-this-integral-for-a-where-a-is-a-real-number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Notice that both integrands represent the same [geometric shape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse), namely $X^4+Y^7=1$.

Comment: That is not a superellipse.

Comment: @Kaster: Technically no, but since we are integrating over a positive interval, it makes little difference.